# How to send web page in email body with css

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, email

I am creating a report on an asp.net web page using an html table and asp.net lables. The finished report I have to send by email in the message body. I've done this with the following c# code:

```
public bool SendEMail(List<string> emailList, string strSubject, string strMessage, bool isHTML)
    {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(strFrom);
            //emailList is a list of email addresses to be sent to
            if (emailList != null && emailList.Count > 0)
                foreach (string em in emailList)
                {
                    msg.To.Add(em);
                }
            else
                return false;
            msg.Subject = strSubject;
            msg.Body = strMessage;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isHTML;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, usePass);
            smtp.Send(msg);
            msg.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
```

This works well but it only gets styles set within the form itself on each control individually. How can I incorperate css set in the html head or in a style sheet?
Also is it possible to include skins?

Comment: Related posts - [Adding css in html that will be sent to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19517245/465053), [How to Inserting HTML and CSS web page in outlook email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50582111/465053) & [Can you link to a CSS file from an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2105963/465053)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look to this chart :

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

I would recommend you to use inline styles instead of adding an external css sheet

Answer (score 4):

styling html emails is a pain in the ass, with each client (gmail/hotmail/outlook/yahoo) applying their own styles to certain high level elements.

a good rule of thumb is to apply inline styles for example:

```
<span style="display:block; background:red;">blah</span>
```

have a look at [campaign monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to see which css rules work and [litmus](http://litmus.com/) if you wish to take the pain out of the testing

Answer (score 0):

This can be done just the same way you'd set the css on a web page. In the message body, you can use a fully formed html document including head tags which can link to an external stylesheet. As long as the css is contained completely within the document, or a full URL is used in the link, it should be fine.

Comment: How can I extract the style content from the head of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the implementation using AlternateViews, this will help you, if you are dynamically generating email body, with styles.

[http://microsoft.com/....alterviews.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews(v=vs.110).aspx)