# How to Inserting HTML and CSS web page in outlook email?

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I want  to insert my HTML and CSS web page in outlook email. I tried it as "Insert as text" option but the CSS file is not loading properly in Outlook. Anyone faced this before?

It is saying like"Missing file in c\Desktop:style.css"
If I had that in desktop and when I forward the mail, Is others able to see the webpage with the CSS?

Comment: try using inline styles

Comment: In most of the case, mails are stripped down to basic html and inline css, you can't have external css or js in html mails. Go for inline css.

Comment: you can declare the styles at the top of your html file in a `<style></style>` section - this way no need to import files

Comment: Related post - [Can you link to a CSS file from an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2105963/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does not have a rendering engine that can read / parse your html, so the css also will never get applied. So the possible solution / steps:

- For css you would need to add inline styles.
- You would need to use images for buttons (paths of these images should be defined or pointing to some fixed server locations)
- You can use packages from javax.mail.jar to created template(html) that can be sent as content to outlook.

Comment: what are you meaning by using Image for button? how to have fixed server locations? @ Abhisek Shetty