# Send actual page by email with php and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want to send the actual page by email, i can send it the problem is that when i open the mail the html dont have the css is obviously but how i can make that look seems the browser?

First I set in a hiddein input the html of the page:

```
var codigo = $("body").html();
$("#codigohtml").val(codigo);
```

And then i take it by selector .val() and put this in the message of the email i put the type of the mail to html.. the problem is with the css.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: YOu might have to use inline CSS for emails. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email)

Comment: you can't have external CSS in an emailed file. It'll be bound by the same "don't load external resources" that mail clients use these days, exactly the same as with images - if external css were automatically loaded, it would be abused to hell and beyond by spammers and tracking agents.

Comment: actually for email to make it look properly you'll have to add "style" attribute to each html element, you might think it's a very complicated task but there are few APIs that you can pass your html to it & it will return the html with rendered "style" attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having a separate CSS stylesheet, just put your CSS directly in your head tag:

```
<head>
    <style>
        /* CSS goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Rest of email -->
</body>
```