# Use external css within an email

Tags: php, css, email, header

I'm trying to have a css file be included in an email but I'm not really sure if that's possible.

What I've tried so far is to send a complete valid html markup within the `message` parameter and include the css as I normally would in a file but that didn't work. Apparently `message` is the body of the email.

So then I guess it must be sent within the `headers` parameter but I'm not really sure how exactly to have that set up?

Here're my headers

```
$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-To: noreply@".strtolower(website_name);
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n
```

What would I need to put in order to include `http://site.com/style.css` as a valid style to apply in the email?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email

Comment: in email template you should write the inline style

Comment: If you sent me an email that tried to fetch a CSS file, I'd consider it junk, and I'd assume you're trying to track if I read your email...

Comment: @JuanMendes How would you even know? :D

Comment: @php_nub_qq Most email clients have an option to ask to load external resources.  It isn't very often that they are used outside of junk mail.

Comment: Google for one, will throw out your external CSS, not 99% sure about this, I'm **100%** sure. Use `inline` CSS. You could've easily Google'd this. Google will literally **tear** your `style` **sheet** apart. *Pardon the pun* ;-)

Comment: `Juan` has a point. For one thing, CSS could hold embedded background images etc., therefore having potential tracking capabilities. And how would he **know**? He knows, and I know; period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linking to external css from an email is not a good idea.  It can work, but most clients are going to block the external request.  Embed the CSS in the HTML of the email itself.

Comment: I got that, but just for the sake of understanding, how is it done?

Comment: You just include a 
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/example.css' type='text/css' />

Comment: Probably because your client is not allowing it, which is why it is a bad idea in the first place.