# Not getting CSS with HTML Based Email In PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

I am trying to receive a loop based generated HTML Table in email but seems like I am getting email but no CSS embedded with it as I am passing the BootStrap library CSS files with the email but it's not getting any CSS at all..So I am wondering that what would be the problem...??

Here is screenshot as :

[image]

Here is my whole code as :

```
<?php


$message .= '<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">';
$message .= '<table class="table table-bordered">';
  $message .= '<thead>';
    $message .= '<tr>';
    $message .= '<th>#</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Username</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Session From</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Session Till</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Uptime</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Download</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Upload</th>';
    $message .= '<th>Total Usage</th>';
    $message .= '</tr>';
  $message .= '</thead>';
  $message .= '<tbody>';


function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
    $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
    if ($factor > 0) $sz = 'KMGT';
    return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f ", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor - 1] . 'B';
}

if (isset($_GET)) {

  $user = $_GET["user"];
}

$x = 1;
$handle = fopen($user, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $split_data = (explode(" ",$line));
    if (in_array('customer=admin', $split_data)) {

foreach (array_values($split_data) as $i => $value) {
if (strpos($split_data[$i], 'user=') !== false) {
    $username = explode("=", $split_data[$i]);
    $username = $username[1];
}
}

foreach (array_values($split_data) as $i => $value) {
if (strpos($split_data[$i], 'from-time=') !== false) {
    $from_time = explode("=", $split_data[$i]);
    $from_time = $from_time[1];
    $from_time = $from_time." ".$split_data[$i+1];
} 
}

foreach (array_values($split_data) as $i => $value) {
if (strpos($split_data[$i], 'till-time=') !== false) {
    $till_time = explode("=", $split_data[$i]);
    $till_time = $till_time[1];
    $till_time = $till_time." ".$split_data[$i+1];
} 
}

foreach (array_values($split_data) as $i => $value) {
if (strpos($split_data[$i], 'uptime=') !== false) {
    $uptime = explode("=", $split_data[$i]);
    $uptime = $uptime[1];
    $download = explode("=", $split_data[$i+1]);
    $download = $download[1];
    $upload = explode("=", $split_data[$i+2]);
    $upload = $upload[1];
    @$total_download += $download; 
    @$total_upload += $upload;
    $total_usage = $total_download+$total_upload;
} 
}



$message .= '<tr>';
      $message .= '<th scope="row">'.$x.'</th>';
      $message .= '<td>'.$username.'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.$from_time.'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.$till_time.'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.$uptime.'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.human_filesize($download,2).'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.human_filesize($upload,2).'</td>';
      $message .= '<td>'.human_filesize($total_usage,2).'</td>';
    $message .= '</tr>';




$x=$x+1;

}
    }

    fclose($handle);
} 



$message .= '</tbody>';
$message .= '</table>';



$to = 'nicefellow1234@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Chances are, gmail is blocking external stylesheets. css for emails should be added in the html between `<style></style>` tags. It's the only way to be sure the email will be styled.

Comment: @Jerodev : Any other way than to to use Embedded CSS code???

Comment: Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email) and also [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/).

Comment: Ahaa..My bad then..Seems like I have to use Inline CSS then..! :D :P

Comment: sidenote: watch out for header injections on them `$_POST['req-email']` vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of September 2016, Gmail accepts *embedded styles* – CSS within `<style>` tags in the head section of HTML documents.

This is in addition to *inline styles*, which were previously the only way to apply CSS in Gmail.

At the same time, Google says nothing about support for *external styles*, which is likely why your Bootstrap styles are failing to load.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/