# How to format my HTML text for email content (smtplib)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, smtplib

I am using SMTPlib to send an email, but I want to format the content with HTML so it looks nicer. Here is my current code:

```
msg = EmailMessage()  # creating an object of EmailMessage class
msg['Subject'] = 'Day 1 of the project'
msg['From'] = Sender_Email  # Defining sender email
msg['To'] = Receiver_Email  # Defining receiver email
msg.set_content(f'''<pre><h3> Hi Dani,</h3>
<p style = "font-family:candara,times,helvetica; font-size:14px;">today is day <b>1</b> since you started this project.

Here is a good quote for you
<i>Fight until the end.</i>

I wish you a good day :)

Until tomorrow,
<p style = "font-family:candara,times,helvetica; font-size:14px; color:#FF0000;"><i>your fateful script</i></p></pre>''', subtype="html")

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(Sender_Email, Password)  # Login to SMTP server
    smtp.send_message(msg)  # Sending email using send_message method by passing EmailMessage object
```

Is there another way to format it? For example by importing a css file?

Comment: i think it is not possible to contain css file in email, therefore it must be inline styling.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email).

Comment: What's with the `<pre>` tags?

Comment: I used the pre tags to keep the line breaks and new lines

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use online html editor such as https://htmlg.com/html-editor/ to format it and then just copy-pasted it into my email content